# Installed MySQL 5.1.x on Mac OS X - Is It Started?

Tags: macos, mac, mysql

I installed using the MySQL-5.1.x.dmg on Mac OS X 10.6, I also installed the package that starts mysql on startup.

When I type:

`mysql -u root -p`

It says "can't connect to local mysql server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

How can I test if MySQL even started?

How can I start MySQL if its not started?

Comment: To see if it's started, check out the Activity Monitor.

Comment: ok its not started....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start MySQL

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &

Add root user:

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password sniggle

Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/osdb.html